# Splitting NSStrings multiple times

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a text file of objects I'm extracting information from, with the data being stored like so:

> name.|description|2013-10-19 23:25:58 +0000|NO|NO
>
> name.|description|2013-10-19 23:25:58 +0000|NO|NO
>
> name.|description|2013-10-19 23:25:58 +0000|NO|NO

To get each line into an array of strings, I do the following:

```
NSArray *objectArray = [saveData componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"];
```

which will yield an array with individual strings like so:

> name.|description|2013-10-19 23:25:58 +0000|NO|NO

I then want to extra each field of each string.

```
 NSMutableArray *items = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (NSString *string in objectArray) {
        [items removeAllObjects];
        [items addObject:[string componentsSeparatedByString:@"|"]];
        for (int i = 0; i < [items count]; i++) {
            NSLog(@"%d      %@", i, [items objectAtIndex:i]);
        }
    }
```

But this simply produces the entire line and not the individual fields?

Edit: My issue was with my original saveData string. Serves me right for not validating it first!

The above code works fine, and produces output as follows:

```
2013-10-20 11:15:11.152 Wakely[3571:11603] 0      (
"name.1",
"desc",
"2013-10-20 00:15:05 +0000",
NO,
NO
)
2013-10-20 11:15:11.155 Wakely[3571:11603] 0      (
"name.2",
"desc",
"2013-10-20 00:15:07 +0000",
NO,
NO
```

)

Shouldn't I be able to grab, say, name1 by using [items objectAtIndex:0]? It seems to have been stored as one whole, single object with line delineations instead of 5 separated strings?

Comment: `[@"name.|description|2013-10-19 23:25:58 +0000|NO|NO" componentsSeparatedByString:@"|"]` gives the expected result. Just tried.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
NSString* test = @"name.|description|2013-10-19 23:25:58 +0000|NO|NO";

NSArray* testarray = @[test,test,test];

NSMutableArray* finalArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

for (NSString* teststring in testarray) {
    [finalArray addObject:[teststring componentsSeparatedByString:@"|"]];
}

NSLog(@"%@",finalArray);
```

Result:

```
2013-10-20 01:46:47.484 test[38523:60b] (
        (
        "name.",
        description,
        "2013-10-19 23:25:58 +0000",
        NO,
        NO
    ),
        (
        "name.",
        description,
        "2013-10-19 23:25:58 +0000",
        NO,
        NO
    ),
        (
        "name.",
        description,
        "2013-10-19 23:25:58 +0000",
        NO,
        NO
    )
)
```

EDIT with your things:

```
NSArray *objectArray = [saveData componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"];

NSMutableArray* finalArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

for (NSString* teststring in objectArray) {
    [finalArray addObject:[teststring componentsSeparatedByString:@"|"]];
}

NSLog(@"%@",finalArray);
```

EDIT 2 :

```
NSArray* firstItem = finalArray[0];
NSString* name1 = firstItem[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to how incmiko did it but using blocks as opposed to the for loop.

```
    NSString* test = @"name.|description|2013-10-19 23:25:58 +0000|NO|NO";

    NSArray *multipleLines = @[test, test, test];

    [multipleLines enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        NSLog(@"%@", [obj componentsSeparatedByString:@"|"]);
    }];
```

Outputs:

```
2013-10-19 19:48:58.522 Strings[407:303] (
    "name.",
    description,
    "2013-10-19 23:25:58 +0000",
    NO,
    NO
)
2013-10-19 19:48:58.523 Strings[407:303] (
    "name.",
    description,
    "2013-10-19 23:25:58 +0000",
    NO,
    NO
)
2013-10-19 19:48:58.524 Strings[407:303] (
    "name.",
    description,
    "2013-10-19 23:25:58 +0000",
    NO,
    NO
)
```

Answer (score 0):

That is because you are adding NSArray as whole object inside your items array. Try with code and it should print the individual item and not the whole array:

```
NSString* test = @"name.|description|2013-10-19 23:25:58 +0000|NO|NO";
NSString* test1 = @"name1.|description1|2013-10-19 23:25:58 +0001|NO1|NO1";

NSArray *objectArray = @[test,test1];

NSMutableArray *items = [NSMutableArray array];

for (NSString *string in objectArray) {
    [items addObjectsFromArray:[string componentsSeparatedByString:@"|"]];
}

NSLog(@"First Item = %@", items[0]);
```